# What does this figurative usage of "swampy" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, figurative-language

> Not to pooh-pooh the Doobs and their smooth, aged take on **swampy**, countrified soul, but this show belongs to Steely Dan. ([source](http://www2.philly.com/philly/blogs/things_to_do/university-city-dining-days-hispanic-fiesta-at-penns-landing-movie-night-at-penn-treaty-park-and-other-great-events-in-philadelphia-july-6-13-20180705.html))

I have checked several dictionaries but haven't found one listing a figurative usage of "swampy". As far as I know the word is only used to describe terrain. What does it mean in this sentence? What does it mean for soul music to be "**swampy**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sub-genre of rock music called *swamp rock*, which originated in the deepest southern states, where the terrain is, in fact, swampy.

The quote is suggesting that the Doobie Brothers' music is influenced by this style.